# Which event should I call to iterate Radio Buttons in a Panel in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I have a Panel containing five Radio Buttons in Windows Forms. I found here various ways to iterate through the Radio Buttons to see which one is checked, but what I don't know is which event should I call to execute the code that iterates (e.g. a foreach loop statement). Is it a Panel's event? Or maybe a Radio Button's?

I'm new to C# .NET Programming, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: When the user clicks the Radio Button within the Panel I need to immediate show a number in a Label's text depending on the user's selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in an event handler for `Click`:

```
myRadioButton1.Click += radio_Click;
myRadioButton2.Click += radio_Click;
myRadioButton3.Click += radio_Click;
myRadioButton4.Click += radio_Click;
myRadioButton5.Click += radio_Click;
```

Note that you could also have assigned the event handler through designer, but the point is that you only need one.

```
private void radio_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your loop code here
}
```

Comment: Yes! Assigning the same event handler to all the radio buttons will do it :) But I suggest using `CheckedChanged` instead of `Click` because the user can check the radio button using the keyboard also. Thanks!

Comment: @rodsarria Beware that `CheckedChanged` also fires due to programmatic changes.  Meaning that it will fire if you do `myRadioButton5.Checked = true;`.